# IBM MQ.Net CertificateLabel, CipherSpec

Tags: ssl, ibm-mq, client-certificates

I am trying to connect to a remote IBM MQ server (v.8.0) and am receiving the error below. I'm using .Net 4.5.2 on Windows 10.
I have modified the SimplePut.exe program that ships with the client install. I think I may be missing something to do with the client certificate I was issued and have installed following their instructions. Possibly the CertificateLabel setting? I am very new to IBM MQ so any help is much appreciated.

```
-h <host> -p 1434 -s TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 -q INS -l connection -k *SYSTEM
```

The error shown at the queue manager when I run the program is as follows:

```
Cause . . . . . :
There is a mismatch between the CipherSpecs on the local  and remote ends of
channel ''. The channel will not run until this mismatch is resolved.
The local CipherSpec is 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256' and the remote
CipherSpec is 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256'.
Recovery  . . . :
Change the channel definition for '' so that both ends have matching
CipherSpecs and restart the channel.
```

Comment: just a quick note. I've also tried the above with *USER

Comment: Did you add the `-s` option?  I don't have a v8.0 SimplePut.cs to review, but the 7.5 version does not have this option.

Comment: No it came from the example - Usage: SimplePut -q queueName -k keyRepository -s cipherSpec [-h host -p port -l channel -n numberOfMsgs -dn sslPeerName -kr keyResetCount -cr sslCertRevocationCheck] from what I've been reading the last couple of days, I think it's a feature in v8.0 managed client. Previously you were unable to specify the cipherSpec because of a limitation in the framework. Or so I believe :)

Comment: What does your app.config specify?  If you have a full MQ client installed and do not specify it will use unmanaged by default.

Comment: Please add the details about your SVRCONN Channel definition to your question as well. You have shown us what the client end is using with your -s parameter. The error suggests the SVRCONN is using something different.

Comment: @JoshMc - nothing set in the app.config, I'll look into this a bit more. re: Windows group policy below, that looks like it to me. I've set the local Windows Group Policy SSL Ciper Suite Order to only have TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 in the list, rebooted, it's still trying to connect as 128. I've also set it on the MQEnvironment.SSLCipherSpec. I've asked the admins the otherside to use the 12 for now as it's a test system. I'll come back to this in a week or so. Will let you know :) Cheers.

Comment: @MoragHughson - Unfortunately I don't have access to the server, I am told on good authority that the channel is configured correctly and that they are using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256. It appears that my .NET program is changing the cipher.

Comment: Is the error in your question from the client side or the server side? If client side then it is saying that the remote end (the server end) is using ..AES_128.. To prove or disprove that fact, you could try changing the client to use ..AES_128.. to see if it now works. If the server end is truly configured to use ..AES_256.. then it should fail! If that works, I'd go back to them for more proof.

Comment: @MoragHughson - from the server side. Thank you, I believe I have been able to resolve this issue using the information provided from JoshMc below. I edited the group policy SSL cipher spec. I am now seeing a different error message in the server logs relating to certificates - AMQ9637: Channel is lacking a certificate. This is probably related to the cipher spec issue here but because it does now appear to be using AES_256 I will mark it as the answer and post another question If I get stuck with this latest problem. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MQ v8.0 Knowledge Center page "[Configuring SSL for managed IBM MQ .NET](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q120700_.htm)" states the following:

> c. If needed, edit the Windows Group Policy to set the CipherSpec, then, for the Windows Group Policy updates to take effect, restart the computer.

and

> a. Set the MQEnvironment or the SSLCipherSpec value to denote the connection as a secured connection. The value that you specify is used to identify the SSL protocol being used (SSL or TLS) and **must match with any preference that you have specified in the Windows Group Policy.**

MQ v8.0 Knowledge Center page "[CipherSpec support for the managed .NET client](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q120610_.htm)" goes into some more detail:

> For the IBM MQ.NET managed client, the SSL settings are for the Microsoft.NET SSLStream class. For SSLStream, a CipherSpec, or a preference list of CipherSpecs, **can be set only in the Windows group policy, which is a computer-wide setting**. SSLStream then uses the specified CipherSpec or preference list during the handshake with the server. In case of other IBM MQ clients, the CipherSpec property can be set in the application on the IBM MQ channel definition and the same setting is used for SSL negotiation. **As a result of this restriction, the SSL/TLS handshake might negotiate any supported CipherSpec regardless of what is specified in the IBM MQ channel configuration.** Therefore, it is likely that this will result in error **AMQ9631** on the queue manager. To avoid this error, **set the same CipherSpec as the one that you have set in the application as the SSL configuration in the Windows group policy**.

---

> **Windows group policy**
>
> When a CipherSpec is set on the Windows group policy, the same CipherSpec must be set for the SSLCipherSpec property value on the SVRCONN channel and in the application. **If the Windows group policy is set to the default, that is the group policy is not enabled/edited for CipherSpec setting, applications must set the same default value of the CipherSpec from the Windows group policy SSL configuration** in the MQEnvironment class or in the MQQueueManager constructor hashtable properties.

---

**UPDATE on specifying cert label with Managed .NET**

MQ v8.0 Knowledge Center page "[Using certificates for the managed .NET client](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q120650_.htm)" goes into detail of the two options to allow MQ to find the cert:

> **Matching certificates by certificate label**
>
> If you set the certificate label, the IBM MQ managed .NET client searches the Windows certificate store with the given label name to identify the client certificate. It loads all matching certificates and uses the first certificate on the list. There are two options for setting the certificate label:
>
> - The certificate label can set on the MQEnvironment class accessing MQEnvironment.CertificateLabel.
> - The certificate label can also be set in a hash table properties, supplied as input parameter with MQQueueManager constructor as shown in the following example.
>     `Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();`
>     `properties.Add("CertificateLabel", "mycert");`
>     The name("CertificateLabel") and the value are case sensitive.
>
> ---
>
> **Matching certificates by string**
>
> If certificate label is not set, then the certificate that matches the string "ibmwebspheremq" and the current logged on user (in lower case) is searched for and used.

---

**UPDATE with additional helpful blog post**

@renz found the IBM developerWorks MQdev Blog posted by Sudhanshu Pant "
[MQ v8: SSL connection in Managed MQ .NET](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/mq_v8_dot_net_samples_can_create_ssl_connection_in_managed_mode?lang=en)" which also has good information with screen shots.

Comment: Hi, apologies I should have said that error is from the remote host (server side). As you can see I am telling it to use TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256. But their logs have it as trying to connect using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256. Which is why I thought I must be missing something. Thanks for taking a look by the way.

Comment: Thanks, restricting the group policy SSL Cipher Suites to only using AES_256 has either fixed the issue or at least forced it to use this cipher only. This has now eluded to the actual issue which is - AMQ9637: Channel is lacking a certificate. I have a post to follow which addresses this issue [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/belinky/entry/digital_certificate_labels_digital_certificate_label34?lang=en)  so will be giving it a go later. Will post a new question if it doesn't work :) Cheers

Comment: @renz Added detail on managed .NET cert label matching.  The second option listed is the way MQ has worked in the past with other non-Java clients and requires the label match a specific format that includes the username running the process, this is what is discussed in the link you provided.  The first option allows you to specify any label you want and is in line with enhancements to MQ v8 and later on all clients and queue managers to allow you to specify a label.

Comment: Thanks for the above I've been struggling with this "CertificateLabel" a bit and have tried a few things this week. This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817966/certificate-label-when-fetching-from-windows-cert-store-for-net-mq-client) mentions how to give it a "friendly name" which did it for me. Cheers

Comment: For me "Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
properties.Add("CertificateLabel", "mycert");" doesn't work. MQEnvironment.CertificateLabel - works fine... Ibm MQ client bug?

Comment: You would need to be passing properties to the `new MQQueueManager` call, ex: `MQQueueManager mqQueueManager = new MQQueueManager(qmName, properties);`.  MQEnvironment is not thread safe, passing a properties hash table is.  For any setting you could set in MQEnvironment there is an equivalent property to add.  Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534711/mqqueuemanager-message-pooling/51545804#51545804) from @Roger for a great example.

Comment: @JoshMc: I looked at sources, CertificateLabel property is ignored. So, I think this is bug.

Comment: What version of MQ did the `amqmdnet.dll` come from?

Comment: @JoshMc: 9.0.0.0. Code fragment: this.msgCompList = MQEnvironment.GetArrayListProperty("msgCmpList", this.properties, MQEnvironment.MsgCompList);
        this.localAddress = MQEnvironment.GetStringProperty("Local Address Property", this.properties, MQEnvironment.LocalAddressSetting);
        this.certificateLabel = MQEnvironment.CertificateLabel; As you see: local addres uses configuration and environment, but for certificate label - only environment.

Comment: @VikciaR agreed it does look like a bug.   Can you confirm it is present also in 9.0.0.5?  I found APARs IT24119 and IJ04255 that describe a similar issue with XMS.NET which relies on amqmdnet.dll. These show as fixed in 9.0.0.4 so they may have also corrected the problem you noted.

Comment: @JoshMc: 9.0.0.5, 9.0.0.4 for me doesn't work at all (in my scenario, error 2538 - I didn't search reason for that). 9.0.0.3 - works same.

Comment: 2538 MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE, can you look at your AMQERR01.LOG on the windows .net client side to see if it provides more details?  Normally that is not a TLS problem.

Comment: Maybe server validation is changed in version 9.0.0.4 and server certificate is checked more strictly. We use simple self signed certificate on the server, client doesn't know about it anything.

Comment: I found what was cause of the error: I made server certificate trusted and everything worked ok. Back to initial problem: property.Add("CertificateLabel", "myLabelName") is ignored in MQ client 9.0.0.5 also.

Comment: @VikciaR looks like the issue you faced was fixed in [IT30545: MQ .NET managed client application returns 2059 when setting certlabel in hashtable properties](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/IT30545) in 9.1.0.7 and 9.2.0.2 (no mention of 9.0, but it is out of support now anyways).