# HP UFT - VBScript/API Testing - Connecting to SSL enabled IBM WebSphere MQ Queue Manager

Tags: vbscript, ssl-certificate, ibm-mq, hp-uft

Using DotNetFactory object of UFT, I am trying to connect SSL enabled channel as below. But its throwing invokation error.  Can anybody please check below VBSCript code and help.

```
strQMgrName = "MQQM"
strMQMDllPath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\WebSphere MQ\\bin\\amqmdnet.dll"
Set oMqEnvironment = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("IBM.WMQ.MQEnvironment",strMQMDllPath)
oMqEnvironment.Hostname = "MQQM.SRVR.COM"
oMqEnvironment.Port = "1234"
oMqEnvironment.Channel = "MQQM.CHNL.SSL"
oMqEnvironment.SSLCipherSpec = "SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
'oMqEnvironment.SSLCipherSpec = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"           'tried with this as well
oMqEnvironment.SSLKeyRepository = "C:\SSLKeyRepository\MQQMKey.kdb"

Set oMQC = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("IBM.WMQ.MQC",strMQMDllPath)
' qmanager name,channel name, connection name
Set oMqQMgr = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager",strMQMDllPath,strQMgrName)

Msgbox oMqQMgr.IsConnected
```

MQQMKey.kdb is placed in the directory C:\SSLKeyRepository which contains other required files MQQMKey.sth and MQQMKey.rdb

I also tried connecting to SSL enabled QM with UFT - API Testing standard activity IBM WebSphere MQ but no result. Please see attached.

[image]

Comment: As explained by the tag descriptions,  VB.NET is neither VBScript nor VBA

Comment: Do you have a full IBM MQ client install?  What version of MQ is the `amqdnet.dll` from?  If you are trying this from the unmanged client (no full IBM MQ client install), this did not support encryption until v8.0.  This question may help you if that is the case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42347768/ibm-mq-net-certificatelabel-cipherspec

Comment: Yes, full IBM MQ client v7.1 is installed.

Comment: v7.1 went out of support on April 30 2017, have you tried with a currently supported version?  What is the exact error you receive?

Comment: Yes, that's a problem v7.1. These SSL certificates are working from the client v7.5. While both 7.1 and 7.5 supports SSL Version 3.0 and TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.2, I am checking as what exactly the SSL/TLS version sent out from my system to server. Looks like this is the only issue.

Comment: I am getting MQRC_SSL_INITIALIZATION_ERROR. While checking further down in the logs, one of the two certificate throws AMQ9633 error - 575010 No certificate chain was built for one certificate. Another certificate throws error regarding extensions - Authority Information Access or CRL Distribution Points.

These two certificates are working great on another machine where WMQ client v7.5 is installed

Comment: I have manually verified the certification path and seems to be everything is in place. Signer certificates as well as personal certificates are pointing to root CA certificate. All certificates in the chain are available and well placed. Not sure where is wrong.

Comment: If you want someone to see your comment use @username (ex for me @JoshMc) in your comment so that SO will let them know you replied.

Comment: If it works with 7.5 and 7.1 is no longer supported why waste time trying to figure out why and instead spend that time upgrading to 7.5?  Do the two certs work from the 7.5 machine to the same queue manager and channel you are having a problem with on 7.1?

Comment: Yes @JoshMc, they works.

Comment: I would just spend the time to upgrade the client to 7.5

Comment: @JoshMc, We have updated WMQ Client to 7.1, but still same issue. Now what might be difference between settings on two windows systems that leading two these errors. Firewall/registry settings?

Comment: There are too many comments on this post.  Please edit your question and add the information you have conveyed in the comments and then click the "x" to the right of the comments to delete them.  Can you check the "Product version" of the amqmdnet.dll file to ensure it is matching the MQ client version installed.