# 2538 error on MQ for SSL channel connection

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

I am using IBM WebSphere MQ 8.0 version.

I have configured one of my channels with "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256" Cipher Spec encryption along with valid certificates installed and mapped to key store path correctly.

My .NET client code is not able to connect with this secured channel. It gives 2538 error continuously.
I have another channel configured without encryption (unsecured). The client code can connect to this channel without any errors.

This is my .NET client code:

```
        Hashtable queueProperties = new Hashtable();
        queueProperties[MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY] = host; // IP address
        queueProperties[MQC.PORT_PROPERTY] = 1541
        queueProperties[MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY] = channel; // channel name
        queueProperties[MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY] = MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED;
        queueProperties[MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY] = "*USER";
        queueProperties[MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY] = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256";
        queueProperties[MQC.SSL_PEER_NAME_PROPERTY] = "CN=FXCMTST1,O=IBM,C=US";
        queueProperties["CertificateLabel"] = "ibmwebspheremqfxcmtst1";
        queueProperties[MQC.KEY_RESET_COUNT] = 0;
        MQEnvironment.SSLCertRevocationCheck = true;
        queueProperties[MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY] = user; // variable
        queueProperties[MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY] = pwd; // variable
        try
        {
            // Attempt the connection
            queueManager = new MQQueueManager(qmgr, queueProperties);
            strReturn = "Connected Successfully";
        }
```

I have also set the MCA User to the valid user with all required access rights.

The above code works fine for the unsecured channel when I remove these lines and replace the channel name with that of unsecured one.

```
    queueProperties[MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY] = MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED;
    queueProperties[MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY] = "*USER";
    queueProperties[MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY] = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256";
    queueProperties[MQC.SSL_PEER_NAME_PROPERTY] = "CN=FXCMTST1,O=IBM,C=US";
    queueProperties["CertificateLabel"] = "ibmwebspheremqfxcmtst1";
    queueProperties[MQC.KEY_RESET_COUNT] = 0;
    MQEnvironment.SSLCertRevocationCheck = true;
```

Am I missing anything in the code or MQ configuration?

UPDATE 1:
I found that the error was due to incorrect path to key database. I had mentioned the path till folder name where the certificates were placed. However it was expected to be the folder name followed by the name of kdb file without extention.

After doing this change, the 2538 error is gone. But now I am getting 2059 error with below error message in log.

"The CipherSpec negotiated during the SSL handshake does not match the required CipherSpec for channel..."

My Channel is configured to have"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256" as I have set in the MQ Explorer. The client code is also sending the same cipher spec. Still it gives 2059 error.

UPDATE 2: As suggested by @JoshMc, I set the group policy and it resolved above error. Then I started getting error "Channel is lacking certificate".

UPDATE 3: This error is gone after I changed the SSLCAUTH to OPTIONAL. Earlier it was set to REQUIRED. Thanks to @JoshMc for pointing out.

Comment: I don't have full client installed. I just use .Net dll in my code to connect with MQ server. Also, I will change  the peer name as you suggested.

Comment: If that is the case then even when doing TLS you do not need to set `MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY` since the dll defaults to Managed mode when no client is installed.  Let me know what the logs show, also performing a client side .Net trace would probably point you in the right direction.

Comment: @JoshMc it is still a good idea to include MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY

Comment: @Roger Agreed, was meaning to point out that removing that line as part of  testing without TLS would not make a difference since no client is installed.  I should have worded better.

Comment: SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY -->D:\\temp\\eClient\\client_certificate,I set this property(without .kdb) but I still take 2538,what is your latest working code sample @AnilSoman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Originally in your question you had the following line of code:

```
queueProperties[MQC.SSL_PEER_NAME_PROPERTY] = "ibmwebspheremqtestqueue";
```

I advised: The `SSL_PEER_NAME_PROPERTY` is meant to validate a portion or all of the DN value of the queue manager cert, so it would be in a format like `CN=x.domain.com,OU=Y,O=Company Inc`, what you have looks like a cert label.

Can you see what errors are generated if any on the queue managers AMQERR01.LOG? What about in the local client AMQERR01.LOG?

You responded with an error from the queue manager:

```
AMQ9660: SSL key repository: password stash file absent or unusable.
```

And you found the error per your update:

> UPDATE: I found that the error was due to incorrect path to key database. I had mentioned the path till folder name where the certificates were placed. However it was expected to be the folder name followed by the name of kdb file without extention.

Now you moved on to getting the following error:

```
The CipherSpec negotiated during the SSL handshake does not match the required CipherSpec for channel...
```

I advised: Managed .net does not use the cipher you specify it is picked up from a Windows policy.  This question and answer should help "[IBM MQ.Net CertificateLabel, CipherSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42347768/ibm-mq-net-certificatelabel-cipherspec/42348037#42348037)".

You advised you fixed the group policy and then moved on to getting the following error when you set `SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)` on the `SVRCONN` channel:

```
channel is lacking a certificate
```

`SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)` tells the queue manager that you are requiring the client to have a certificate. The client will always require the queue manager to have a certificate no matter what `SSLCAUTH` is set to.

Assuming you have the queue manager configured to perform `CONNAUTH` to validate the user and password you are sending and you have set `ADOPTCTX(YES)` on the `CONNAUTH`'s `AUTHINFO` object, then having `SSLCAUTH(OPTIONAL)` is a reasonable setting as this means all the data between the client and queue manager will be encrypted and the connection is authenticated by the id/pw. Even if you have `SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)`, unless you also configure the `SVRCONN` to match on a specific `DN` value via either the channel's `SSLPEER` property or a `CHLAUTH TYPE(SSLPEERMAP)` rule's `SSLPEER` property it is not providing any form of authentication.

Comment: I finally kept the SSLCAUTH to OPTIONAL and it worked fine. I did this because we wanted to go with One way encryption approach instead of two way. And the connection is working now. Thanks for your help and knowledge sharing @JoshMc